# "A link to the server could not be established" to my database in PHP

Tags: php

I Found this Warning:

> Successful database connection, happy coding Raj2!!!
>
> Warning: mysql_query(): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: NO) in /home/u590617868/public_html/action.php on line 4 Warning: mysql_query(): A link to the server could not be established in /home/u590617868/public_html/action.php on line 4.
>
> not sucsessful

my code is:

```
<?php
      include_once "DB_connect.php";
      $uName = $_POST['username'];
      $sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO members('username') VALUES('$uName')");
      if ( $sql )
      { 
         echo "sucsessful"; 
      }
      else
      { 
         echo "not sucsessful"; 
      }
?>
```

Comment: I assume this is MySQL?

Comment: From your error, it looks like the password was wrong? Check the credentials again and see whether the user has a password or not.

Answer (score 0):

You've no database connection or it is not included/closed. Please post your complete code.

Answer (score -2):

Please structure your code a little better. Just a tip.

The syntax should go something like this:

```
$query="INSERT INTO members (username) VALUES ('$uName')";
if(mysql_query($query)){
     echo "Success";
}else{
     echo "Fail";
}
```

It doesn't seem like that's the issue at hand. You have a permissions issue. Post the pseudo-content of your DB_connect.php file (change address,username, and password if you feel the need to)